# How can I resolve relative paths in an ASP ListView template?

Tags: asp.net, listview

I use a ListView to display (funnily enough) a list of data, including a hyperlink. Here is my item template (ascx file):

```
<a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(CType(Container, ListViewDataItem).DataItem, "ID","/Pages/Image.aspx?id={0}").ToString()%>'
    title='View <%# DataBinder.Eval(CType(Container, ListViewDataItem).DataItem, "Title")%>'>
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(CType(Container, ListViewDataItem).DataItem, "CardNo")%> - 
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(CType(Container, ListViewDataItem).DataItem, "Title")%></a>
```

I'm having problems with the link resolving correctly as this same template is re-used multiple times across the project and fails for pages in a subfolder. I guess I'm looking for a `Server.MapPath` equivalent so that I could use ~ to get a path relative to root but how do I insert that into my HTML?

**Update:** The problem is caused by the fact that my project runs in a subfolder of LocalHost root on my machine. In Production the project is in the root itself and this problem doesn't occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`ResolveClientUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx) or [`ResolveUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx).

Comment: perfect but it looks like a code behind thing, how do I add it to my template?

Comment: Using `<%# ResolveUrl(DataBinder.Eval(CType(Container, ListViewDataItem).DataItem, "ID","/Pages/Image.aspx?id={0}")) %>` as the `href` value should work.